# Change the background of a CollapsingToolabarLayout

Tags: android, imageview

I'd like to change the background of in `ImageView` inside a `CollaspingToolbarLayout`. Here is what I tried to do:

activity_main.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collapsingimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/teszt1"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    collapsingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.collapsingimage);
    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("  ");

dynamicToolbarColor();

}

private void dynamicToolbarColor() {

    Bitmap b = imageUrltoBitmap(imgurl);
    collapsingimage.setImageBitmap(b);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hhg);

        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                int colorPrimary = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
                int colorPrimaryDark = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(colorPrimary));
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(colorPrimary));
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
        });
}
```

So I'd like to load another image instead of I added in the xml file and I set the ImageView's background but nothing happens. Have you any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To change the color use the property `app:contentScrim`, i see that you are using the color `color/colorPrimary`:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

If you need to do this programatically don´t use `pallete`, use directly:

```
  collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

 int colorPrimary = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
 collapsingToolbarLayout.setBackgroundColor(colorPrimary);
 collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(colorPrimary);
 collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(colorPrimary);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what your code is exactly the same as mine. Could tell me what should i do different with `app:contentScrim` ?

Comment: Do you have to change the color right? change the color of app:contentScrim=

Comment: I'd like to change in runtime in the java code. And I'd like to change the background of the ImageView inside of the Toolbar.